# Display BLOB type in JSF view

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, blob

I'm creating a Java EE application for my company with JBoss AS7, JSF2, MySQL, EJB and JPA.

I have a dataTable in my JSF view with several row which contains the data retrieved from my database. In this data, I have a BLOB column which can contain any file type like image, PDF, text.

I want to put a link in each row which open the file in a new window.

1. How can I convert BLOB type to byte?
2. How can I do this kind of work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I convert BLOB type to byte?*

Just put `@Lob` annotation on the `byte[]` property of your JPA `@Entity`.

---

> *How can I do this kind of work?*

You need to let JSF generate desired links in the table, with the entity ID as request parameter.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/fileservlet?id=#{entity.id}" target="_blank">#{entity.filename}</h:outputLink>
    <h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Then create a simple [file servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which streams the `byte[]` to the response in `doGet()` (obvious parameter validation and exception handling omitted).

```
@WebServlet("/fileservlet")
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private EntityService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Entity entity = service.find(request.getParameter("id"));
        response.setContentType(entity.getContentType());
        response.setContentLength(entity.getContent().length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(entity.getFilename(), "UTF-8") + "\"");
        response.getOutputStream().write(entity.getContent());
    }

}
```

Where `getContent()` returns the `@Lob byte[]` property.

Comment: Ok thanks BalusC. I have also found your link : http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Comment: You're welcome. That link concerns "plain JDBC", not JPA/EJB.

Comment: can i look all the code ? private EntityService service; <--- i was wondering how this was build ?